# Ng-multiselect dropdown not returning to its previous state after filtering data table

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have a working application that when you select an item from ng-multiselect-dropdown, it filters a data on a table. But when you clear the selected item, the contents of the table vanishes and the dropdown displays "no data available". I want the table to return to its initial state after dropdown item has been deleted

.ts

ngOnInit():void{
this.dropdownList = this.fullbatches;}

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'id',
  textField: 'createDate',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};

onItemSelect(item: any) {
this.selectedIds.push(item.id);
}
onSelectAll() {
this.selectedIds = this.data.map(x => x.id);
this.resetTable();
}
onDeSelectAll() {
this.selectedIds = [];
this.resetTable();
}
onItemDeSelect(item: any) {
this.selectedIds.splice(this.selectedIds.indexOf(item.id), 1);
this.resetTable();
}
resetTable() {
this.fullbatches = [...this.data.filter(x => this.selectedIds.includes(x.id))];
}

*NB* fullbatches is the instant of the data from the db
```

.html

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  Create Date
  <div>
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
      [placeholder]="'Select'"
      [settings]="dropdownSettings"
      [data]="data"
      (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
      (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
      (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
      (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll()"
      (onChange)="resetTable()"
    >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
  </div>
</th>
```

Comment: `this.data = [...this.data.filter(x => this.selectedIds.includes(x.id))];` it should do the job. Since your data set is stored in `data` variable. Though I have one doubt what's the point of `this.dropdownList = this.fullbatches` it then?

Comment: Dropdowlist populates the data in fullbatches and displays in its dropdown data from the db, fullbatches refers to an Interface in the application.